# C++ nlohmann json multiple json from file

Tags: json, file, c++11, stream

I've been messing around with nlohmann's json library for a while but I can't figure out what I'm missing.  I'm trying to read a bunch of json objects in at once and the file has 1 json object per line and I'm trying to parse all of them and store it into a vector.

```
int main(){
vector <json> alljSon;
std::ifstream i("test.json");
while (i.good()) {
    json j;
    i >> j;
    alljSon.push_back(j);
}

return 0;
```

}

The problem is that if there's more than 1 json object, it gives me a the error message.
    "parse error - unexpected '{'; expected end of input"   std::basic_string,std::allocator >.  Any fixes?

Comment: Can you post your code as it stands with more than 1 json object?

Comment: What do you mean? This is all of the code I have at the moment.  Are you asking about the test.json file?

Comment: nlomann json library doesn't support reading concatenated jsons from a stream. see: https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues/210.

Answer (score 0):

A nice approach could be parsing the whole file into a JSON, then iterating through that JSON and adding the values to the vector.

```
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using nlohmann::json;

int main()
{
    std::vector <json> alljSon;
    std::ifstream i("test.json");
    json j = json::parse(i);
    for (auto it = j.begin(); it != j.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (j.is_array())
        {
            alljSon.push_back(it.value());
        }
        else
        {
            // If it's not an array, it's an object, and from what I understood you want the key too.
            alljSon.push_back({it.key(), it.value()});
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[How to iterate over JSON objects.](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues/67)